# How to disable URL change when posting a comment? Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, comments, disable

When a user posts a comment and clicks submit, the URL of the current page changes. For example:

It was like this - `http://example.com/uncategorized/test-post-1/`

It became like this - `http://example.com/uncategorized/test-post-1/#comment-1428`

Or even like this: `/?Unapproved=1246588&moderation-hash=40271ae6cdb307b9243b08107da795ae#comment-1246588`

This is standard Wordpress comment form in single posts.

How to make the URL not change?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.  Questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se].  Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: `ajax` is what you're looking for! Change the "comments form" to a "custom form" and then, send and process it via `ajax`.